# My code breaks when I change the function name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 different files. When I change the function name, one of the files is broken and my code doesn't work. If I have the same function name in both files, the other one is broken. I don't get what's going on.

This works:
[image]

it doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you're changing two function names, not just one.  Since you are changing onEdit to onEditPre, do you have a trigger set to run onEditPre?

Comment: `onEidt()` is a special function (a trigger). If you change its name it stops work as a trigger.

Comment: Go to triggers and add an installable trigger for onEditPre